# Fetching URLs from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I go through each key of my dictionary 'mydict', and fetch its key values which are URLs in my case, and open each url in a separate browser session every time?

just trying to automate where each url will open in a new browser session every time.

```
mydict = {
    'set_one_urls': ['https://www.yahoo.com', 'https://www.google.com'],
    'set_two_urls': ['https://www.hotmail.com', 'https://www.godaddy.com']
}

for key in mydict():
    for value in key:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='../drivers/chromedriver.exe')
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get(value)
        time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get each set of URLs along with the name of the set by looping through [`mydict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
for set_name, url_set in mydict.items():
    for url in url_set:
        # do something with URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code:

```
import time
import webbrowser

mydict = {
    'set_one_urls': ['https://www.yahoo.com', 'https://www.google.com'],
    'set_two_urls': ['https://www.hotmail.com', 'https://www.godaddy.com']
    }

for key, value in mydict.items():
    for link in value:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(link)
        time.sleep(3)
```